# How to get value set in javascript from code-behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I set value in a hidden field like this:

```
((TextBox)ctrl).Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById('" + 
  ((BasePage)Page).GetControl(Page, "ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField").ClientID + 
  "').value.concat('" + row.RowIndex + ",');");
```

In page source it looks like this:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPNewTitlesStatus_ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField').value.concat('0,');"
```

I want to be able to retrieve and use this value from code-behind on postback (button click):

```
string ChangedRowsIndices = ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField.Value.TrimEnd(',');
```

But because of some reason, ChangedRowsIndices is always empty. Could you please help me with this? What am I doing wrong?
Here is the hidden field:

```
<input id="ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would accept, but I didn't get any solution that would work.

Comment: Did you find a solution on your own?  Add that solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Looking through your old questions, a lot of people have taken a lot of time to provide some excellent responses. You either need to reply to their answers or update your question to indicate why you're still having difficulties. If one of the answers isn't exactly correct, but got you started on the right track, you can still accept the answer with a correctional comment. If you eventually figured out a solution or a workaround, post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I don't want to be ungrateful. But here is the situation: in my previous discussion, I needed to solve a particular problem. I realize that people tried hard to help, but unfortunately they did not succeed. I did not get closer to the solution than I had been in the beginning. I still don't have the solution, and it is now too late to search for it. If you insist, I can pick any answer and "accept" it, but is it really right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not use the runat=server place a name here

```
    <input id="ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField" type="hidden"    
name="ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField_ID" />
```

and read the data on post back like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField_ID"]
```

If you left it with the runat="server" get it with the UniqueID

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField.UniqueID]
```

### One more

You have a bug on value, to set the value use `document.getElementById('theid').value = 'new value';`
get a render like

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPNewT‌​itlesStatus_ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField').value = 'new value'
```

Now you type it as jQuery way.

Comment: I am getting error:error CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Form' and no extension method 'Form' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) BTW, my GridView is in UserControl.

Comment: I tried this: Page.Response.Form["ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField"];

Comment: I tried Request, and the ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField was not found amont keys.

Comment: @dpreznik if not found, add a name by your self and search for the name

Comment: @dpreznik in the input control, with the id add and a name, I update my answer try the request.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now it is found, but the value is "". I wonder why it is empty.

Comment: @dpreznik because you must set the value as document.getElementById('ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPNewTitlesStatus_ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField').value = 'new value'

Comment: You are right, that worked. I use "+=" instead of "+", because I need not one index, but indices of all changed rows. Thanks!!